# JS Keydown event doesn't fire on zebkit canvas

Tags: javascript

I have a [keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) to prevent some default events, so that i can overwrite them.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
function logKey(e) {
    console.log(" ~ logKey ~ e", e);

    list = [
        "a",
        "b",
        "t"
    ]

    if (e.ctrlKey == true && list.includes(e.key)) {
        console.log("prevent!");
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Now this works great, but only partly. I have a large canvas that is made with a library called [zebkit](http://www.zebkit.org/dark/about.html) and when focused on that, the event does not fire.

The library does provide it's own [events:](http://www.zebkit.org/dark/docs.ui.event.html)

```
zebkit.ui.events.on("keyPressed", function(e) {
    console.log(" ~ zebkit.ui.events.on ~ e", e);
    return false;
});
```

But they don't provide the prevention of default event's. How do i get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to attach the event listener to the canvas element as well,

```js
// add these two lines
const canvas = document.getElementById('<enter-your-zebkit-canvas-id>');
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

window.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
function logKey(e) {
    console.log(" ~ logKey ~ e", e);

    list = [
        "a",
        "b",
        "t"
    ]

    if (e.ctrlKey == true && list.includes(e.key)) {
        console.log("prevent!");
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This would probably work for a lot of other libraries, but zebkit won't let me attach any events, other than zebkit's own to it's canvas. +1 for the suggestion though.